# How to route an dynamic url?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I am defining this route to an edit button:

```
<a href="/editTasks/{{ $task->id }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit task</button></a>
```

The url is generated fine but the page is not found. I am returning a view with my `TaskController@edit` with this route:

```
Route::get('/editTasks/{{ $task->id }}', 'TaskController@edit');
```

Can someone help me out figuring what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your declaration of route parameters is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining routes, the route parameters should only have one `{` around them. Also, you should not use a variable in the declaration but a name for the variable.

In your example, this could be a valid declaration:

```
Route::get('/editTasks/{id}', 'TaskController@edit');
```

More information can be found in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters

---

It is also recommended to use route names, so the url can be automatically generated.

For example:

```
// Route declaration
Route::get('/editTasks/{id}', 'TaskController@edit')->name('tasks.edit');

// In view
<a href="{{ route('tasks.edit', [$task->id]) }}">Edit task</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single `{` instead of double, so it needs to be the following in your route:

```
 Route::get('/editTasks/{taskId}', 'TaskController@edit');
```

And in your `edit` function:

```
public function edit($taskId) { }
```

The double `{` in the template is correct as this indicates to retrieve a variable

**Extra information/recommendation:**

It is recommended to let the variable name in the route match the variable in your function definition (as shown above), so you always get the expected variable in your function. If they do not match Laravel will use indexing to resolve the variable, i.e. if you have multiple variables in your route pattern and only use one variable in the function it will take your first route parameter even if you might want the second variable.

Example:

If you have a route with the pattern `/something/{var1}/something/{var2}` and your function is `public function test($variable2)` it would use `var1` instead of `var2`. So it it better to let these names match so you always get the expected value in your function.

Answer (score 2):

no you have to define in your route just like this :

```
Route::get('/editTasks/{id}', 'TaskController@edit');
```

you don't have $task in your route and you dont need to write any other thing in your route. in your controller you can access to this id like this :

```
public function edit($taskId) {

}
```

and only you do this

Comment: You are partially correct, it works if only 1 route paramter is specified, but if you have for example a route with the pattern `/something/{var1}/something/{var2}` and your function is `public function test($variable2)` it would use var1 instead of var2. So it it better to let these names match so you always get the expected value in your function.

Comment: Here and for this question there is not any other parameter. If there is other parameter yes you are right we CAN use name in route.

Comment: That's true, I have added this in my question as a recommendation with explanation instead of a necessity in this case

Comment: I agree that it is not incorrect ;), that is why i deleted my comment where I said it was and upvoted ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use ["Route Model Binding"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding). Your route should be like this:

```
Route::get('/editTasks/{task}', 'TaskController@edit');
```

And in Controller use something like this:

```
public function edit($task){

}
```